# android:exported="true" in manifest file used api targetapi 31 but still error in react native

Tags: android, react-native

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Answer (score 0):

i have solve this problem. the problem was in plugin manifest file and i just updated plugin .